# no matching function for call to std::vector<std::tuple> push_back

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, tuples

I have a sample program containing 6 timepoints using `high_resolution_clock::now()` from standard `chrono` header. I take differences b/w each of them resulting in 3 differences and caste them as `auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();` to microseconds.

I have another variable named durations which is assigned as follows: `auto durations = std::make_tuple(duration1,duration2,duration3);` containing previous time-point differences.

I have to push this tuple into an vector, so I have introduced `std::vector<std::tuple<std::chrono::microseconds,std::chrono::microseconds,std::chrono::microseconds>> list;` However on using `list.push_back(durations);` I get an error as :

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:36:29: error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::tuple<std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000ll> >, std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000ll> >, std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000ll> > > >::push_back(std::tuple<long long int, long long int, long long int>&)'
     list.push_back(durations);
```

---

I tried to search about `std::chrono::microseconds` and other `std::chrono::duration` stuff [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) but wasn't successful in rectifying the problem.

I know this has something to do with my negligence of type system, but I'm unable to locate that error. Any help would be appreciated, & here is ideone [link](http://ideone.com/6xxOa1).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

void function()
{
    long long number = 0;

    for( long long i = 0; i != 2000000; ++i )
    {
       number += 5;
    }
}

int main()
{
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t5 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    function();
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t6 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t4 - t3 ).count();
    auto duration3 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t6 - t5 ).count();

    auto durations = std::make_tuple(duration1,duration2,duration3);

    std::vector<std::tuple<std::chrono::microseconds,std::chrono::microseconds,std::chrono::microseconds>> list;
    list.push_back(durations);

    cout << duration1 << " -- "<< duration2 << " -- "<< duration3 << " -- ";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created a tuple of 3 integers and you're trying to add it to a vector of 3 durations.

> I take differences b/w each of them resulting in 3 differences and caste them as `auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();` to microseconds.

Why are you calling `count()` on the durations after doing the `duration_cast` to convert to microseconds?

Just keep the values as `microseconds` objects and you can add them to the vector:

```
auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 );
auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t4 - t3 );
auto duration3 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t6 - t5 );
```

Comment: also I would like to thank you for your work on cpp :)

Answer (score 4):

The type of `std::chrono::microseconds::count()` is not `std::chrono::microseconds`, it's some signed integral type.

```
auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
//decltype(duration1) is not std::chrono::microseconds
```

As such, you can't use your `duration*n*` variables for a vector expecting `microsecond` values.

The fix is easy, just defer your call of `count` until you try and print the contents.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple: don't call `count`.

`std::chrono::microseconds` is (in your case) a typedef for the type `std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000ll> >`. That is also the type you get from doing `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 )`.

However, that is not what you're assigning to `duration1`. You're assigning the result of calling the `count` function on that type. And that returns the number of ticks as a number (`long long int` in your standard library's case), and not as `duration`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a type mismatch.

```
auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count()
```

Actually gives you a `long long` in your case and not a `std::chrono::microseconds`.  You can fix this by using [`decltype()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) and changing

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::chrono::microseconds,std::chrono::microseconds,std::chrono::microseconds>> list;
```

To

```
std::vector<decltype(durations)> list;
```

[Live Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/992944f3df3698ae)